# Weird jordan.m fail

Tags: matlab, matrix

I tried to compute the Jordan form of this 9x9 matrix:

```
 0     1     1     1     1     0     1     0     0
 1     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1
 1     1     0     1     0     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     0     0     1     0     1     0
 1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
 1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

And got this message:

> Warning: Found roots of the minimal polynomial that cannot be
>   determined in terms of radicals. [linalg::jordanForm]  Error using
>   eval Undefined function or variable 'FAIL'.
>
> Error in sym/double (line 937)
>               X = eval(Xstr);
>
> Error in jordan (line 21)    V = double(jordan(sym(A)));

Anybody knows what's going on?

Comment: That is likely a bug; it runs fine on my machine (R2012b x64, w7x64). Which version you have? Wait; why do you have syms out there, though?

Comment: Dunno, when I asked "who A" MATLAB claimed it's a double matrix. But I'll check again, I'm not at that machine now.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg I think Acorbe meant to ask why are you converting `A` to symbolic using `sym` when instead you could just do `V = jordan(A);`. [`jordan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/jordan.html) function can handle both symbolic and numeric matrix.

Comment: @mythealias: Sorry for late followup. I am not actually converting anything, I am giving jordan.m a double matrix - that's what's weird. But I think it might be a paths problem - "which jordan -all" gives me two results, both in "toolbox\symbolic\symbolic" - maybe I'm missing a toolbox or something?